# ngRepeat with ngAnimate set "data-ng-animate= 2" on my element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I dont know why but ngRepeat add `data-ng-animate=2` attr on my element.
Why its happening?

**I write this:**

```
 <div class="aip-main-con-item animate-repeat"
      ng-repeat="event in events | 
      filter : searchEvent | 
      orderBy : 'date'">
 </div>
```

**And I'm get this:**

```
<div class="aip-main-con-item animate-repeat ng-scope"
     ng-repeat="event in events |
     filter : searchEvent |
     orderBy : 'date'" 
     data-ng-animate="2"
     style="">
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: have you included angular-animate.js library?

Comment: and have your module have dependency of `ngAnimate` (i think it has)?

Comment: Yes and yes too guys

Comment: So you do want animations and they are working, but you just want to know why this attribute is used?

Comment: @Jack exactly!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in [the source code here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/07849779ba365f371a8caa3b58e23f677cfdc5ad/src/ngAnimate/animateQueue.js#L3) the `data-ng-animate` attribute is used to track the state of the animation:

```
var PRE_DIGEST_STATE = 1;
var RUNNING_STATE = 2;
```

So basically it's just storing on the element itself the state of its own animation. In your case (`2`) that it's running. If you follow `NG_ANIMATE_ATTR_NAME` through that file you can follow it from getting added, updated, and finally removed from the element.